# can't access to value tag for show data in jquery , mysql , php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

the below code is `jquery` code:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#srchtxt").keyup(function(){
        var addresshome = $("#srchtxt").val();
        $.post("adrespath",{address:addresshome},function(res){
         var json = JSON.parse(res);
            var lenths = json.length;
            for(var i = 0;i <= lenths;i++)
                {

            var city = json[0];
            var state = json[1];
                    var optionli = "<li id='item'><a href='#' value='"+res+"'>"+city+"-"+state+"</a></li>";
            $(".resultsearch .ul").append(optionli);
            }
        });
    });
    $(".ul li#item a").each(function(){
        $(this).click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var index_address,address;
            index_address = $(this).parent().index();
            alert(index_address);
            address = $(this).eq(index_address).attr("value");
            $("#srchtxt").attr("value",address);
        });
    });
    $("#srchbtn").click(function(){
        alert($("#srchtxt").val());
    });
});
```

and the below code is `html` code:

```
    <input type="search" name="srchtxt" id="srchtxt"/>
<div class="resultsearch">
        <ul class="ul">  
        </ul>
        </div>
    <a href="#" id="srchbtn"></a>
```

and the below code is `php` code:

```
<?php
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $querysrch = "select city,state,bolv from tbl where city like '%".$address."%' or state like '%".$address."%' or bolv like '%".$address."%'";
    $ressrch = mysqli_query($cnt,"SET NAMES 'utf8'");
    $ressrch = mysqli_query($cnt,"SET CHARACTER 'utf8'");
    $ressrch = mysqli_query($cnt,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
    $ressrch = mysqli_query($cnt,$querysrch);
    $arry = array();
    if(mysqli_num_rows($ressrch) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ressrch)){
            $addressres = $row['city']."-".$row['state']."-".$row['bolv'];
            $arry[] = $row['city'];
            $arry[] = $row['state'];
        }
    }
    else
    { 
        $arry .= "<li id='item'><a href='#' value='not found'>notfound</a></li>";
    }
    echo json_encode($arry);
    ?>
```

i want when keyup chaarcter show result and when i select the li a tag show to me value tag in jquery please help me

Comment: little confused in your question where is your srchbtn and srchtxt

Comment: i edited you can see

Comment: did you get value on $("#srchtxt").val();

Comment: not get value what do i it??

Comment: i want when result show with click on lia atag the value write into srchtxt and when click on srchbtn alert or show the srctxt value but when i click on li a i don't see result or value tag

Answer (score 0):

i think your code also works fine but you forget to add id on anchor tag while appending it on ul. if you append more then one anchor tag than you should use class because there can't be a two anchor tag with same id which will make conflict. or you can use onclick attribute on your anchor tag

append your anchor tag like this

```
var optionli = "<li id='item'><a href='#' value='"+res+"' onclick='show_value()'>"+city+"-"+state+"</a></li>";
```

and js function

```
function show_value(){
     alert($("#srchtxt").val());
}
```

Comment: did it fixed you problem